# How do I convert indices in json to int?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to plot the data in this json to based on date. How do I convert the "created_at" date to int for the dataframe? Getting TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

url = 'https://api.oilpriceapi.com/v1/prices/past_week'
headers = {
'Authorization': 'Token XXXXXXXXXXX',
'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

response = requests.get(url = url, headers = headers)
data = response.json()
print(data)

dates = (data['data']['prices']['created_at'])
values = (data['data']['prices']['price'])

df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':dates, 'values':values})
df['dates']  = [pd.to_datetime(i) for i in df['dates']]

plt.line(dates, values)
```

error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-db4fdff870ee> in <module>()
     14 print(data)
     15 
---> 16 dates = (data['data']['prices']['created_at'])
     17 values = (data['data']['prices']['price'])
     18 

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

json:

```
{'status': 'success', 'data': {'prices': [{'price': 32.5, 'formatted': '$32.50', 'currency': 'USD', 'code': 'BRENT_CRUDE_USD', 'created_at': '2020-05-27T16:04:00.466Z', 'type': 'spot_price'},......
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: What about the `int` class?

Comment: `prices` looks to be a list of dictionaries, so you will to iterate thru to pull out `created_at` for each element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me give you a light correction.
First you can get the `dates` and `prices` as following

```
dates = [item['created_at'] for item in data['data']['prices']]
values = [item['price'] for item in data['data']['prices']]
```

Other should work as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

This is a dictionary present inside a list:

```
data['data']['prices']
>>[{'price': 32.5,'formatted': '$32.50','currency': 'USD','code': 'BRENT_CRUDE_USD','created_at': '2020-05-27T16:04:00.466Z','type': 'spot_price'}]
```

Hence try

```
data['data']['prices'][0]['created_at']
```